# Windows Kernel: Retrieving function addresses inside modules

Tags: windows, winapi, kernel, reverse-engineering, windows-kernel

I am trying to call a function in the kernel that is located in the win32kfull.sys module.
I got the base address of the module using ZwQuerySystemInformation.
Now I want to find out the offset of the NtUserSendInput function located in the win32kfull.sys module.
When I open win32kfull.sys in IDA Pro and open the function, I get two addresses:
[image: IDA Pro location of NtUserSendInput]

Unfortunately I don't know how to add the offsets to the base address of win32kfull.sys to get the function address.

I would be grateful if someone could explain to me how I could proceed now.

Comment: I don't understand the question. There's only a single address shown in the screenshot.

Comment: By two addresses I mean "raw offset" and "virtual location".
In principle I just want to know:
How do I get the address of NtUserSendInput? (Neither "raw offset", nor "virtual location" point me to NtUserSendInput when I add them to the module base address of win32kfull.sys.

Comment: i guess you even dont know how to get `offset` of pdb symbol. so for what you need this at all ?

Comment: I need the address of NtUserSendInput because I want to call the function in the kernel.
Am I on the wrong way if I try to find out the address with IDA this way?

Comment: @moccajoghurt - `NtUserSendInput` is exported symbol, so no problem take it address

Comment: Also win32k addresses for Nt* routines can be found via KeServiceDescriptorTableShadow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `NtUserSendInput` is an exported function, which means that the PE format of the image (specifically export directory) will let you know the address of the function if you parse it correctly.

This is a better solution, getting the offset out of IDA Pro would give you **version specific** address, which means that i would have to get the offset for each build of win32kfull.sys and each time there is new version you gonna have to update your driver.

So, if you have the base address of win32kfull.sys you can treat it as the start address for the PE structure and parse it, there are plenty of tutorials online about how to do that.